# Detect devices on local network for client-server connection in C++

Tags: c++, android, cross-platform, udp, broadcast

I'm trying to implement an auto-connect feature for my Android application DroidPad, which is basically a TCP server running on an Android phone which the PC application connects to.

To make the process easier for the user, is there any way in (portable?) C++ to scan the IP addresses on the local subnet, possibly ones with a certain open port? I've tried using UDP broadcasting, but couldn't get it to work. I'm currently using the wxWidgets toolkit for GUI and libraries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: [wxServDisc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxservdisc/). It uses mDNS (aka Zeroconf / Bonjour) to discover devices on a subnet, and is also based on wxWidgets.